# bean is not creating

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

```
       package com.filter.service;
       import java.util.ArrayList;
         import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

     import com.filter.dao.UserDao;

   @Service
  public class ServiceClass {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

private ArrayList data(int testId)
{
    return this.userDao.fetchData(testId);
}
```

}

```
           package com.filter.dao;
           import java.util.ArrayList;
          import org.hibernate.Session;
         import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
          import org.hibernate.query.Query;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.filter.model.TeSectionQue;

    @Repository
  public class UserDao {


      @Autowired
      SessionFactory sF;

       @Autowired
      HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ArrayList fetchData(int testId)
{
    Session session = sF.openSession();
    ArrayList <TeSectionQue> userData=null;
    System.out.println("print");
    try {
        String SQL_QUERY="from te_section_que as 0 where 
     0.test_no=?";
        Query<?> query= session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
        
        userData=(ArrayList<TeSectionQue>)query.list();
        
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("exception not available");
        return null;
    }
    return userData;
  }

 }



package com.filter.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import com.filter.service.ServiceClass;

 @Controller
 public class MainController {

   @Autowired
  ServiceClass serviceClass;

   @Autowired(required=true)
  @Qualifier(value="ServiceClass")
  public void setServiceClass(ServiceClass serviceClass){
    this.serviceClass = serviceClass;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String view()
  {
    System.out.println("Test");
    return "index";
    }
   @RequestMapping(value="/testId", method= RequestMethod.POST)
   public String fetch(HttpServletRequest req)
  {
    String testId=req.getParameter("search");
    System.out.println(testId);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
       return "";
    }
  }



          package com.filter.model;

         import javax.persistence.Column;
         import javax.persistence.Entity;
      import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
      import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
       import javax.persistence.Table;

   @Entity
  @Table(name="wet_user_response")
   public class User {

   @Column(name = "sno", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int sno;
  @Column(name = "test_pattern", nullable = false)
  private String test_pattern;
  @Column(name = "test_pattern", nullable = false)
   private String tlevel;

   @Column(name = "result_view", nullable = false)
   private String result_view;

   @Column(name = "bexam_name", nullable = false)
    private String bexam_name;

@Column(name = "bcomp_code", nullable = false)
private String bcomp_code;

@Column(name = "test_domain1", nullable = false)
private String test_domain1;

@Column(name = "RQNO1", nullable = false)
private String RQNO1;

@Column(name = "RANS1", nullable = false)
private String RANS1;

@Column(name = "RSEC1", nullable = false)
private String RSEC1;

@Column(name = "RMAK1", nullable = false)
private String RMAK1;

@Column(name = "qtext1", nullable = false)
private String qtext1;

@Column(name = "SEL_SELECTION1", nullable = false)
private String SEL_SELECTION1;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(name = "name1", nullable = false)
private String name1;

@Column(name = "exam_name", nullable = false)
private String exam_name;

@Column(name = "TestStartTime", nullable = false)
private String TestStartTime;

 @Column(name = "RQNO", nullable = false)
private String RQNO;

@Column(name = "RSEC", nullable = false)
private String RSEC;

@Column(name = "RMAK", nullable = false)
private String RMAK;

@Column(name = "RANS", nullable = false)
private String RANS;

@Column(name = "UANS", nullable = false)
private String UANS;

@Column(name = "wheeboxID", nullable = false)
private int wheeboxID;

@Column(name = "perQustionTimer", nullable = false)
private String perQustionTimer;

@Column(name = "assign_by", nullable = false)
private int assign_by;

@Column(name = "test_id", nullable = false)
private int test_id;

@Column(name = "cuk_id", nullable = false)
private int cuk_id;

@Column(name = "key_sno", nullable = false)
private int key_sno;

@Column(name = "questionsFlagged", nullable = false)
private String questionsFlagged;


public int getSno() {
    return sno;
}
public void setSno(int sno) {
    this.sno = sno;
}
public String getTest_pattern() {
    return test_pattern;
}
public void setTest_pattern(String test_pattern) {
    this.test_pattern = test_pattern;
}
public String getTlevel() {
    return tlevel;
}
public void setTlevel(String tlevel) {
    this.tlevel = tlevel;
}
public String getResult_view() {
    return result_view;
}
public void setResult_view(String result_view) {
    this.result_view = result_view;
}
public String getBexam_name() {
    return bexam_name;
}
public void setBexam_name(String bexam_name) {
    this.bexam_name = bexam_name;
}
public String getBcomp_code() {
    return bcomp_code;
}
public void setBcomp_code(String bcomp_code) {
    this.bcomp_code = bcomp_code;
}
public String getTest_domain1() {
    return test_domain1;
}
public void setTest_domain1(String test_domain1) {
    this.test_domain1 = test_domain1;
}
public String getRQNO1() {
    return RQNO1;
}
public void setRQNO1(String rQNO1) {
    RQNO1 = rQNO1;
}
public String getRANS1() {
    return RANS1;
}
public void setRANS1(String rANS1) {
    RANS1 = rANS1;
}
public String getRSEC1() {
    return RSEC1;
}
public void setRSEC1(String rSEC1) {
    RSEC1 = rSEC1;
}
public String getRMAK1() {
    return RMAK1;
}
public void setRMAK1(String rMAK1) {
    RMAK1 = rMAK1;
}
public String getQtext1() {
    return qtext1;
}
public void setQtext1(String qtext1) {
    this.qtext1 = qtext1;
}
public String getSEL_SELECTION1() {
    return SEL_SELECTION1;
}
public void setSEL_SELECTION1(String sEL_SELECTION1) {
    SEL_SELECTION1 = sEL_SELECTION1;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getName1() {
    return name1;
}
public void setName1(String name1) {
    this.name1 = name1;
}
public String getExam_name() {
    return exam_name;
}
public void setExam_name(String exam_name) {
    this.exam_name = exam_name;
}
public String getTestStartTime() {
    return TestStartTime;
}
public void setTestStartTime(String testStartTime) {
    TestStartTime = testStartTime;
}
public String getRQNO() {
    return RQNO;
}
public void setRQNO(String rQNO) {
    RQNO = rQNO;
}
public String getRSEC() {
    return RSEC;
}
public void setRSEC(String rSEC) {
    RSEC = rSEC;
}
public String getRMAK() {
    return RMAK;
}
public void setRMAK(String rMAK) {
    RMAK = rMAK;
}
public String getRANS() {
    return RANS;
}
public void setRANS(String rANS) {
    RANS = rANS;
}
public String getUANS() {
    return UANS;
}
public void setUANS(String uANS) {
    UANS = uANS;
}
public int getWheeboxID() {
    return wheeboxID;
}
public void setWheeboxID(int wheeboxID) {
    this.wheeboxID = wheeboxID;
}
public String getPerQustionTimer() {
    return perQustionTimer;
}
public void setPerQustionTimer(String perQustionTimer) {
    this.perQustionTimer = perQustionTimer;
}
public int getAssign_by() {
    return assign_by;
}
public void setAssign_by(int assign_by) {
    this.assign_by = assign_by;
}
public int getTest_id() {
    return test_id;
}
public void setTest_id(int test_id) {
    this.test_id = test_id;
}
public int getCuk_id() {
    return cuk_id;
}
public void setCuk_id(int cuk_id) {
    this.cuk_id = cuk_id;
}
public int getKey_sno() {
    return key_sno;
}
public void setKey_sno(int key_sno) {
    this.key_sno = key_sno;
}
         public String getQuestionsFlagged() {
          return questionsFlagged;
}
     public void setQuestionsFlagged(String questionsFlagged) {
        this.questionsFlagged = questionsFlagged;
}
```

}

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans- 
             4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context- 
            4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

        <tx:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.filter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    name="viewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

 <bean name="ds" 
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system11"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
</bean> 


<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    name="factory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop 
   
 key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hdm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>
                com.filter.model.User
            </value>
            <value>
                com.filter.model.TeSectionQue
            </value>
            <value>com.filter.model.TeQuestionBank</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate"
    name="hibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionfactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.filter.model.User" name="userDao">
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>

</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
    name="transactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionfactory"></property> 
</bean>
```

Error msg======

Sep 14, 2021 3:09:33 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.filter.service.ServiceClass' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Sep 14, 2021 3:09:33 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.filter.service.ServiceClass' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1096)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:767)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)

Comment: Hi, please format your question to be readable and post some of your code, e.g. this `userDao` class/interface

Comment: plz take my system on remote and solve this...

Comment: Sorry but thats not how it works. You have to post a meaningful question and provide code samples that represent the problem you face. Good questions get good answers, if you don't edit your question and add all the required info you won't get any answers.

Comment: What I asked you is very simple, please edit your question and paste the `UserDao` code.

Comment: please see my all code

Comment: solve my code plz and telm me whats wrong is my code

Comment: Please try to format your code its almost unreadable, nobody will try to help you unless we can read your code. Take your time and post a well structured question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Error**:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'serviceClass'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.filter.service.ServiceClass' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

In your **MainController** you are "autowiring" `ServiceClass`

- here (using the field `serviceClass`):

  ```
   @Autowired
   ServiceClass serviceClass;
  ```
- and here (using the setter method `setServiceClass`):

  ```
    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="ServiceClass")
    public void setServiceClass(ServiceClass serviceClass){
        this.serviceClass = serviceClass;
    }
  ```

It would work if you didn't annotate with `@Qualifier(value="ServiceClass")`, however it is better to completely remove the second "autowiring" of ServiceClass.

In other words in your `MainController` class keep only one `@Autowired`,

```
@Autowired
ServiceClass serviceClass;
```

and delete the setter `setServiceClass` along with all its annotations.

Comment: its not been working. i tried many times .

Comment: @suficst It should be working, unless you have other errors, please edit your question, **add** the modified `MainController` class and **add** the new error stacktrace

Comment: its solved thnkss

Comment: @suficst Nice! if my answer helped you solving your issue please consider upvoting/check it as correct.